# cmake complains "Could NOT find X11 (missing: X11_X11_LIB)",but all x11 related stuff got installed already

Tags: cmake, x11

I got this error in ubuntu 21.04

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:165 (message):
  Could NOT find X11 (missing: X11_X11_LIB)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:458 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/vtk-9.0/patches/99/FindX11.cmake:366 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/vtk-9.0/VTK-vtk-module-find-packages.cmake:209 (find_package)
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/vtk-9.0/vtk-config.cmake:131 (include)
```

but all x11 related stuff got installed already by

sudo apt install libx11*

I can find related includes and libs in their location:

```
alex@x-space:~/workspace/Scene/Debug$ sudo locate libX11
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.4.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.4.0

alex@x-space:~/workspace/Scene/Debug$ lh /usr/include/X11/
total 1.1M
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.3K Apr 15  2020 ap_keysym.h
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Apr 20 18:48 bitmaps
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.0K Aug 17  2020 CallbackI.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.5K Aug 17  2020 Composite.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.7K Aug 17  2020 CompositeP.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.0K Aug 17  2020 ConstrainP.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.6K Aug 17  2020 Constraint.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.4K Aug 17  2020 ConvertI.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.6K Aug 17  2020 Core.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8.4K Aug 17  2020 CoreP.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.4K Aug 17  2020 CreateI.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.1K May 20 01:00 cursorfont.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.8K Apr 15  2020 DECkeysym.h
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Sep 14 21:02 dri
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.2K Aug 17  2020 EventI.h
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Sep 30 18:01 extensions
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Sep 30 15:59 fonts
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.2K Aug 17  2020 HookObjI.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6.0K Apr 15  2020 HPkeysym.h
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Sep 14 21:04 ICE
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  405 May 20 01:00 ImUtil.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  13K Aug 17  2020 InitialI.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  63K Aug 17  2020 Intrinsic.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6.8K Aug 17  2020 IntrinsicI.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9.5K Aug 17  2020 IntrinsicP.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 172K Apr 15  2020 keysymdef.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.8K Apr 15  2020 keysym.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.6K Aug 17  2020 Object.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6.8K Aug 17  2020 ObjectP.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5.4K Aug 17  2020 PassivGraI.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.6K Aug 17  2020 RectObj.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6.3K Aug 17  2020 RectObjP.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.9K Aug 17  2020 ResConfigP.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.7K Aug 17  2020 ResourceI.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5.1K Aug 17  2020 SelectionI.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  18K Aug 17  2020 Shell.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  212 Aug 17  2020 ShellI.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  13K Aug 17  2020 ShellP.h
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Sep 14 21:04 SM
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  30K Aug 17  2020 StringDefs.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.0K Apr 15  2020 Sunkeysym.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.2K Aug 17  2020 ThreadsI.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  17K Aug 17  2020 TranslateI.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.4K Aug 17  2020 VarargsI.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.8K Aug 17  2020 Vendor.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.5K Aug 17  2020 VendorP.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.5K Apr 15  2020 Xalloca.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.9K Apr 15  2020 Xarch.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.5K Apr 15  2020 Xatom.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.8K Feb 25  2021 Xauth.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  21K May 20 01:00 Xcms.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.4K Apr 15  2020 Xdefs.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6.3K Feb 25  2021 Xdmcp.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14K Apr 15  2020 XF86keysym.h
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Sep 14 21:59 Xft
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7.7K Apr 15  2020 Xfuncproto.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.3K Apr 15  2020 Xfuncs.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  20K Apr 15  2020 X.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  31K May 20 01:00 XKBlib.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.6K May 20 01:00 XlibConf.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  98K May 20 01:00 Xlib.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  40K May 20 01:00 Xlibint.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  506 May 20 01:00 Xlib-xcb.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.3K May 20 01:00 Xlocale.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5.1K Apr 15  2020 Xmd.h
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Sep 18 07:29 Xmu
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.1K Apr 15  2020 Xosdefs.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.3K Apr 15  2020 Xos.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  33K Apr 15  2020 Xos_r.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7.6K Apr 15  2020 Xpoll.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  52K Apr 15  2020 Xproto.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.7K Apr 15  2020 Xprotostr.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5.9K May 20 01:00 Xregion.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  11K May 20 01:00 Xresource.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  13K Apr 15  2020 Xthreads.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.9K Aug 17  2020 Xtos.h
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Sep 14 21:02 Xtrans
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  21K May 20 01:00 Xutil.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.9K Apr 15  2020 Xw32defs.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.8K Apr 15  2020 XWDFile.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.3K Apr 15  2020 Xwindows.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.3K Apr 15  2020 Xwinsock.h
```

Why do I still get this error?